# What character encoding is this, I do not recognize it?

Tags: php, json, encoding

I'm pulling data from a JSON source, and it contains a field of name, but sometimes names are outside ASCII range (special characters).

In particular, I'm working with this:

- Source name: Màrrát
- JSON: "char_name":"M\u00e0rr\u00e1t"

My question is: **what is the encoding method used by the JSON site**, so I can check if they match?

Comment: The "encoding" is called "JSON" and you simply `json_decode()` it.

Comment: JSON_encoded values are encoded in UTF-8 ( \u00 denotes it ), next you can parse it in javascript and have those accents on chars displaying correctly

Comment: @Jack \u00 doesn't "denote UTF-8". It's simply a textual representation of a Unicode code point or UTF-16 sequence. It doesn't really have anything to do with UTF-8.